# App not showing in Notification Center for IOS8+

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ios8, nsnotificationcenter

I am working on Cordova app which is using Urbanaisrship push notification.

When I load my build in to iPhone-4 which have version(7.1), I can see my app into device setting-->Notification Center.

But when I load same build in to my other device Iphone 5s which have version 8.2 my app is not showing in to setting-->Notification Center.

So any buddy can tell me what's wrong with IOS version 8.2 ?

Comment: in iOS 8 apps are present in setting app with their independent row,see at bottom section of settings app ,scroll through it

Comment: yes but i the app should be enabled Notifications which is not in IOS8 while IOS7 it's working.

Comment: add this piece of code in app delegate file and try.  if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
//            [self printApplicationState];
            [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
            
            [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

        }

Comment: @muku can you tell me where should i add your mentioned code.? I am developing app with cordova so i have not enough knowledge about ios code.

Comment: check for <yourproject>delegate file in your project and in method - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions OR you can search this method in search

Comment: You are talking about this, right? - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
#else
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
#endif
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

Comment: yes find that method and add the above piece of code in that method.hope this serve your purpose

Comment: Bingo.... Thanks It's working now. You save me today.

Comment: You reply in comment. Cna you give proper answer of this then only i can make as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//other code
// add this piece of code
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    }

}
```

Add this piece of code to your appdelegate file